# applicationWillResignActive notification uncaught on device

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsnotifications

I'm trying to save a simple string on a simple .plist file when the application is closing.

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    self.kmOld.text = [array objectAtIndex:0];

    [array release];
}


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(applicationWillResignActive:)
                                      name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification 
                                      object:NULL];
[super viewDidLoad];
```

}

Then follow the applicationWillResignActive method:

```
 - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSString *text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",kmNew.text];
    NSLog(@"%@",text);

    if ([text intValue]>0) {
        NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:text, nil];

      BOOL success = [array writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
        NSLog(@"%d",success);
        [array release];
    }
    [text release];
}
```

**This work fine on the simulator**, but it seems to be ignored by the device...
Where is the problem? Thanks...

Comment: Are you sure your view is loaded when that notification is sent? If the view is not visible memory pressure on the device might cause it to be unloaded.

Comment: Yes, i'm pretty sure it is.. Anyway the views in my app are only two, and they aren't unloaded when I switch between them, so I don't think this is the cause of the bug..

Comment: Silly question, but are you running iOS 4+?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging/ for a good overview of the UIApplication lifecycle. Depending on the iOS version your app is running on and the action causing your app to terminate/background you may not be listening for the correct notification and may need to observe UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification as well.

[image: iOS <4]

[image: iOS 4+]

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful (on device).. So if I would develop an app supported both in iOs 4+ and 3.x should I implement both applicationWillResignActive and applicationWillTerminate methods?

Comment: That's right, you want to consider both cases (resign active and terminate).